# How to set the size of text in PagerTitleStrip

Tags: android, android-studio, android-scrollable-tabs

I am trying to make scrollable tabs and want to set the size of the title .How can I do this as I cant set the text size in PagerTitleStrip in the xml.Can some one tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below style in your styles.xml

```
<style name="viewPagerTitleStrip">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_dark_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

And then

```
<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        style="@style/viewPagerTitleStrip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp" />
```

Comment: using gradient I can set the background of the title?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how to do it: 
in your xml:

```
 <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabText"/>
```

and in styles.xml

```
<style name="MyCustomTabText">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```